# сравнение качества работы модели LR по rmse отдельно по тестовой и тренировочной выборке

Tags: python, машинное-обучение

В формулy RMSE передаются y_test и y_pred:

**np.sqrt(metrics.mean_squared_error(y_test, y_pred))**

От меня требуется вычислить RMSE отдельно по тренировочной части данных и отдельно по тестовой, чтобы более комплексно оценить модель. Какие параметры я должна передавать в формулу RMSE, чтобы получить такое разделение?  Ведь и y_test и y_pred передаются одновременно...

спасибо, только я запуталась в переменных: У меня : X = data[['area', 'level', 'levels', 'rooms']] y = data['price']; далее X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=42); lm.fit(X_train, y_train); в конце получаю: y_pred = lm.predict(X_test); вывожу на экран y_test и считаю RMSE: np.sqrt(metrics.mean_squared_error(y_test, y_pred)) .... какой набор переменных в моем случае надо подставить в формулу RMSE для проверки? "Проверка: np.sqrt(metrics.mean_squared_error(y_training, f(x_training))) np.sqrt(metrics.mean_squared_error(y_test, f(x_test)))" –
Nika Triquetra
14 часов назад
я пробовала: np.sqrt(metrics.mean_squared_error(y_train, y_pred)), выдает ошибку: ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [8666710, 2166678].

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 0):

Набор данных состоит из двух частей: x, y. Т.е. исходные данные и эталонные результаты.
В идеале `y == f(x)`, где f-модель.

Делите данные на две части `[*x]==[*x_training]+[*x_test]`,  `[*y]==[*y_training]+[*y_test]`. Пару x_training, y_training - используете для обучения модели, она называется тренировочной выборкой. Пару x_test, y_test - не используете, она называется тестовой выборкой.

Проверка:
`np.sqrt(metrics.mean_squared_error(y_training, f(x_training)))`
`np.sqrt(metrics.mean_squared_error(y_test, f(x_test)))`

Comment: спасибо, только я запуталась в переменных:  У меня : X = data[['area', 'level', 'levels', 'rooms']]
y = data['price']; далее X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=42); lm.fit(X_train, y_train); в конце получаю: y_pred = lm.predict(X_test); вывожу на экран y_test  и считаю RMSE: np.sqrt(metrics.mean_squared_error(y_test, y_pred)) .... какой набор переменных в моем случае надо подставить в формулу RMSE для проверки? "Проверка: np.sqrt(metrics.mean_squared_error(y_training, f(x_training))) np.sqrt(metrics.mean_squared_error(y_test, f(x_test)))"

Comment: я пробовала: np.sqrt(metrics.mean_squared_error(y_train, y_pred)), выдает ошибку: ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [8666710, 2166678]. К сожалению, скрины в комментах не прикрепляются

Comment: Ваше y_train - истинные значения, которые вы вытащили из датафрейма методом y_train = df['price'].pop(), для определения метрики rmse (или какой-либо другой) вам нужно сравнить с тем, что предсказала модель исходя из исходных данных X_train. То есть Вам нужно получить что-то вроде y_train_pred = lm.predict(X_train). А потом подставляется в метрику np.sqrt(бла-бла(y_train, y_train_pred)) - здесь мы получим значение rmse на train-выборке! Для получения rmse на test-выборке необходима пара векторов y_test и y_test_pred. В последнем комментарии Вы подставили не ту пару векторов.